# Serial Key in innosetup

Tags: c#, inno-setup, web-platform-installer

Is possible to make a setup program with Inno setup which ask serial key for continue install the application?
Thanks

Comment: You tagged it with C#. Couldn't you write a C# installer that does this?

Answer (score 0):

Password= in the [setup] section.
Drawback is that the setup can't use other bitmaps for the installer program

Comment: Related documentation: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_password